# Alternative for the wc_add_to_cart_message hook in Woocommerce for WP

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I used the add to cart message hook in Woocommerce to edit the text and remove some classes from certain buttons. It seems this hook is now deprecated in Woocommerce 2.1 and I can't find an alternative.

I want to remove the 'button' class from the 'Continue Shopping' button. This class gets defined in the Woocommerce core which I want to leave unedited for proper future updates.

The line I'm trying to edit is located in woocommerce/includes/wc-cart-functions.php line 94.

```
$message = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __( 'Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce' ), $added_text );
```

Did anyone find a proper alternative for this hook yet? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This worked for me

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'custom_add_to_cart_message' );
function custom_add_to_cart_message() {
    global $woocommerce;

        $return_to  = get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop'));
        $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forwards">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __('Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );
    return $message;
}
```

Edited: Thanks for the correction Kaarel Kaspar

Answer (score 3):

Woocommerce 2.3+,

```
    add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'custom_add_to_cart_message' );
    function custom_add_to_cart_message( $message  ){
    global $woocommerce;

    $added_text = __( 'Product was successfully added to your Network Kit.', 'woocommerce' );
    // Output success messages
    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) :

        $return_to  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url() );

        $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', $return_to, __( 'Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce' ), $added_text );

    else :

        $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ), __( 'View your Network Kit', 'woocommerce' ), $added_text );

    endif;

    return $message;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this thread is a bit old, I found the link to my same question about deprecated since version 3.0! from the first link on G search engine, so here is what fixed my errors.

Errors:

Notice: The wc_add_to_cart_message filter is deprecated since version 3.0! Use wc_add_to_cart_message_html instead. in /sitepath.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4329

Notice: woocommerce_get_page_id is deprecated since version 3.0! Use wc_get_page_id instead. in /sitepath.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4329

As you can see the solution is in the problem (error message).

Use `wc_add_to_cart_message_html`

Use `wc_get_page_id instead`

Answer (score 0):

this could be a solution. please change if you have better ways or ideas:

the filter-name has changed with the 2.1-version to "wc_add_to_cart_message"

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'foo' );
function foo() {

$product_id = $_REQUEST[ 'product_id' ];

if ( is_array( $product_id ) ) {

    $titles = array();

    foreach ( $product_id as $id ) {
        $titles[] = get_the_title( $id );
    }

    $added_text = sprintf( __( 'Added &quot;%s&quot; to your cart.', 'woocommerce' ), join( __( '&quot; and &quot;', 'woocommerce' ), array_filter( array_merge( array( join( '&quot;, &quot;', array_slice( $titles, 0, -1 ) ) ), array_slice( $titles, -1 ) ) ) ) );

} else {
    $added_text = sprintf( __( '&quot;%s&quot; was successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce' ), get_the_title( $product_id ) );
}

// Output success messages
if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) :

    $return_to  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url() );

    $message    = sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" class="alert-link">%s &rarr;</a> %s',
        $return_to, __( 'Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce' ),
        $added_text
    );

else :

    $message    = sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" class="alert-link">%s &rarr;</a> %s',
        get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ),
        __( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ),
        $added_text );

endif;

return $message;
}
```

hope it helps.
cheers

Comment: wc_add_to_cart_message has 2 parameters: message and product_id. According to this, it's better to change your `add_filter` statement to `add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'foo', 10, 2 );`, change signature of `foo` function to `function foo($message, $product_id)` and delete string `$product_id = $_REQUEST[ 'product_id' ];`.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020 this is the filter required: wc_add_to_cart_message has been deprecated. Here I am simply wrapping the message in span:

```
//New added to card message text
function filter_wc_add_to_cart_message_html( $message, $products ) { 
  return "<span>".$message."</span>"; 
}; 
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'filter_wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 10, 2 );
```