# Set cart permalink when cart is not empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, message, cart

I have no cart link set in the backend of WooCommerce. Instead I have the cart redirected to the checkout page. This works fine, however now I end up with empty urls. When I add a product to the cart I get the message 'successfully added to the cart, see the cart here'. 'See the cart here' is linked to `wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' )`, but this is not set.

Is it possible through a function to set the `wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' )` ONLY when items are in the cart?

I tried something like:

```
function custom_continue_shopping_redirect_url ( $product_id ) {
    $url = "http://www.url.com"; // Add your link here
    return $url;
}
add_filter('wc_add_to_cart_message', 'custom_continue_shopping_redirect_url');
```

But that is obviously replacing the whole add to cart message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed some code. try it this way:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'custom_continue_shopping_redirect_url', 10, 2 );
function custom_continue_shopping_redirect_url( $message, $product_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;

        // $permalink = get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('shop')); // replaced by:
        $permalink = get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('cart')); // your link here.
        $message    = sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button wc-forwards">%s</a> %s', $permalink, __('Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce'), __('Product successfully added to your cart.', 'woocommerce') );
    return $message;
}
```

You will have to fine tune your replacement link. You can also change the text…

References:

- [Hookr: wc_add_to_cart_message](http://hookr.io/filters/wc_add_to_cart_message/)
- [Alternative for the wc_add_to_cart_message hook in Woocommerce for WP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832684/alternative-for-the-wc-add-to-cart-message-hook-in-woocommerce-for-wp)
- [Custom Add To Cart Messages - GitHub](https://gist.github.com/ChromeOrange/3423933)